# Teradata Rest Services

Tags: rest, odbc, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I would like to use REST Services on Teradata, the TDB is on windows installed, how can I install REST Services on windows, did someone hier already have tried it and can tell steps or is there a good video explain that well? Thx

Comment: There's no Teradata running on Windows, do you mean the Teradata Express VM?

Comment: Yes sorry teradata installed in Vmware, and the question  how to install REST Services and connect it to Teradata, in Guide they said, that i should have Linux Suse Enterprise Server is that an extra OS that I should install or i can th rest api in VMware direct implement. thx

Comment: The OS of TD Express *is* Suse Enterprise Server, if you got the TD Rest package you can install it in the VM (but you need to assign more memory to it, probably at least 8 GB)

Comment: OK, can you tell me plz? if I run the server in my machine can other users who have rights run  the localhost:xxxx, in their web browser on windows? thank you so much for your answers, it's rare to found something about this topic

Comment: I don't know about the specific Rest Services, but you can access the VM from the network using the assigned IP-address (of course not if you use *Host-only* network), not *localhost*, this is only from within the VM. I usually use a *Bridged* network, *ifconfig* will show you the actual ip-address.